# Why are there problems when deriving from a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Base{
protected: T i, j;
}

template<class T>
class Derived: public Base<T>{
public: void set_i_j(T x, T y) { i = x; j = y;}
}
...
```

If I try this code I get 2 errors, that 'i' and 'j' weren't 'declared in this scope'. I looked for answers and I found that if I write this it works:

```
this->i = x; this->j = y;
```

Now the question is why does it work with 'this->'? Or, better put, why doesn't it work without?

Note: This is just a simple example, I was trying to make circular lists derived from simple lists.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Don't the answers explain why?

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks. And no they didn't. But someone marked as duplicate and I found the answer. Thanks guys.

Comment: Another nice question ... my vote goes in for that. Feel free practicing upvoting now that you reached that level ;-)

Comment: Thank you! For the answer on the other thread as well.